# What’s wrong with this edit adding an App Store link to an answer?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

What is wrong with me adding a link to the app in the App Store [in this suggested edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/239552)? Was it misunderstood to not be a link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with that edit being rejected, and while I was not one to make the actual rejection, this would have been my reasoning for rejecting it:

- The post already contained a link to the official website for the app and a couple of other links to get started, such as a signup link.
- The app is cross platform and does not need to be purchased from the App Store, such that the App Store link need not be the foremost link of the post.
- The (huge) ‘Download on the App Store’ badge takes up unnecessary space in the answer.

Edit rejection reasons can be custom, but in this case the one used by both reviewers was one of the standard choices. Even so, it's worth looking at the precise language used in the reason since it very much applies here.

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Also @nohillside has some excellent [words of wisdom](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3290/37797):

> Also keep in mind that an edit in the review queue must be reviewed by several other users. Let‘s make the most of their time by making the edits substantial.

Comment: Totally agree. I've rejected quite a few similar edits for the exact same reasons. In addition, my personal preference is that when a link does need to be added, that a plain link more than suffices without the need for the App Store badge.